# I am unable to push my source code to Salesforce org after connecting it. It's showing component failures and errors in the package.xml

Tags: salesforce, version, visualforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEn77.png)

i am facing push code to salesforce org(lwc session push or deploy code command does not fire)   error show me component failure invalid version to package.xml error help me to push source code to org successfully in vs code to salesfroce org

Answer (score 0):

Craft an url similar to `https://baa.my.salesforce.com/services/data` but with your target org domain in it. It will probably say that highest version available is 58 (Summer release). 59 (Winter release) is available only as a preview in some sandboxes and won't hit productions till mid-October.

You need to go to your `package.xml` file and lower the number towards the bottom of the file. You may have to repeat it in few places like the component's "meta-xml" file or sfdx-project.json file.

Or change your deployment target to point to a Winter preview sandbox.